# How to made tab bar in 3 pages

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomePageView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    @State var selectedIndex = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack  {
                Image("avel-chuklanov-DUmFLtMeAbQ-unsplash")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 250)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    Spacer()
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
            }
                Form{
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                    Text("Employee List")
                }
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                            Text("List")
                    }
                Text("Profile")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                        Text("Profile")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made this tab bar but it doesn't work as well how to fix it
and I want it can use to be in profileview and list view, so I want it has their own files

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. You may want to check out [ask]

Comment: what doesn't work in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the question, add `.tabViewStyle(.page)` to your `TabView` to have 3 pages instead of the 3 icons.

```
TabView {
 ...
 }.tabViewStyle(.page)  // <--- here
```